# Two different code lines opened and read the same file

Tags: python, file, append

I need to open a file (example actions.txt)
and pass it whole to a list (example actions [ ])

repeat the same operation again with many other files

```
actions = greetings = []

with open (os.getcwd() + "/files/" + "actions.txt") as temp  :

    for a in temp :
        actions.append(a)        


with open (os.getcwd() + "/files/" + "greetings.txt") as temp  :        

    for a in temp :
        greetings.append(a)
```

The problem is that in both cases is open and read the first file, perhaps there is an obvious error but I do not notice

Thank you very much in advance.

I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Linux Mint 13 (great) with the excellent IDE Netbeans

PS:

I tried to change the directory a "files" with "os.chdir"

also close the object "temp" with "temp.close()"

I put in the second line of code " temp2" instead of "temp"

I do not know what else to do.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.  What was the result of your code and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: actions = greetings = [] acts as reference! just create 2 lists normally and it will work.

Comment: Or, even more simply: just do `actions = list(temp)` in the first `with` and `greetings = list(temp)` in the second, and scrap the loops and initialization entirely. Looping over an iterable to call append on an empty list does exactly the same thing as just making a list out of the iterable… except that you can get it wrong.

Comment: yes Kobi, thank you, that was the bug.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Marking an answer as accepted is more than sufficient; there is no need to also edit the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
actions = greetings = []
```

This line makes `actions` and `greetings` both refer to the *same* list.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[1]
>>>
```

As you can see, even though I haven't even touched `b`, it still gets `1` appended to it because `a` and `b` are the same list.

So, to fix your problem, make that one line of code two:

```
actions = []
greetings = []
```

or do this:

```
actions, greetings = [], []
```

Actually, as @abarnert said in the comment, what you want can be done as simply as this:

```
with open(os.getcwd() + "/files/" + "actions.txt") as temp:
    actions = list(temp)
with open(os.getcwd() + "/files/" + "greetings.txt") as temp:        
    greetings = list(temp)
```

Comment: ICodez Thank you very much, my intention was to simply compacting the code indicating that the two were lists, 

I put them apart and problem solved!

I'm new to Python and I'm learning things every day
I appreciate your great help,
and the other guys, thanks